# ios 13 bluetooth crash with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ios13, avplayerviewcontroller

I am having weird crash with my app: Whenever i have a bluetooth headset connected to my app and i open a viewcontroller where i am using AVPlayerViewController the app just crashes. Their are no logs in the debugger, the app just shuts off.

If i disconnect the bluetooth and go to the same page the app works fine, i am able to play the video go to fullscreen and perform all tasks without any issues. Also everything works fine on ios 12 as well.

I have already included both: Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description and Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description.

Kindly help i am stuck on this issue since past 4 days.

Crash happening on IOS version: 13.3.1

Comment: Posting this for anyone else facing this issue: Turns out there is a bug in AVKit which was confirmed by apple's iOS tech support team. 
Here is a workaround which worked for me: 
Set the "playervc.showsPlaybackControls = false" 
Now create your custom overlays buttons like: Play, Pause, Slider, close button and add all of them to playervc.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(buttons/views) 

tip: i did all the setup inside AVPlayerViewController extension

Comment: Have you [set the category](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616442-setcategory?language=objc) of the [playback](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback?language=objc) with the [Bluetooth option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptionallowbluetooth?language=objc)? E.g. `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error]`.